# (Proof explanation) In integral domain let there be a prime ideal $(a)$ then $a$ is irreducible.

Tags: ring-theory, proof-explanation, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> **Theorem** Let $D$ be an integral domain and let $(a)$ be a prime ideal of $D$, then $a$ is irreducible.

*Proof*: Assume that $1\neq a=bc$, we have to show that either $b=1$ or $c=1$. Because $bc=a\in(a)$ we have that $b\in(a)\vee c\in(a)$. Assume that $b\in(a)$, then $b=ad$ for some $d\in D$ thus $a=bc=adc$ which shows that $dc=1$ "Because $D$ is integral domain, it follows that $c=1$" similarly for $c\in(a)$ we have that $b=1$.

Now, my question is why should $dc=1$ imply $c=1$? What if it is the case that $c$ is inverse of $d$? The OP is Proposition 6 in http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math330/div.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true, in a general integral domain, that $dc = 1$ implies $c = 1$; what one *does* have is that $c$ and $d$ are *units*, that is, divisors of $1$, and this is enough to show $a$ irreducible, since by definition the divisors of an irreducible such as $a$ are its *associates*, i.e., elements which are of the form $ua$, where $u$ is a unit.

In fact, it is easy to find integral domains in which $cd = 1$ without $c = 1$ or $d = 1$; indeed,

$cd = 1 \Longrightarrow (-c)(-d) = 1, \tag 1$

so we could take

$c = d = -1; \tag 2$

going a little further, consider the Gaussian integers

$\mathcal Z = \{a + bi \mid a, b \in \Bbb Z; i^2 = -1 \}; \tag 3$

since

$\mathcal Z \subset \Bbb C, \tag 4$

$\mathcal Z$ is clearly an integral domain; but the units in $\mathcal Z$ are $\pm 1$, $\pm i$.

***Note Added in Edit, Sunday 2 September 2018 6:21 PM PST:***  I response to our OP Michal Dvorak's comment below, I provide the following remarks:

A *unit* in a commutative unital ring $R$ is a divisor of $1_R$; that is, $u$ is a unit if there exists $v \in R$ with $uv = vu = 1$; clearly, units are invertible.

Units in $R$ are to be carefully distinguished from the *multiplicative identity*; since we call a ring $R$ with $1_R \in R$ such that

$r1_R = 1_R r = r, \; \forall r \in R \tag 5$

a ***unital ring*** or ***ring with unit***, it can get a little confusing.  But $1_R$ is unique, whereas there may be many *units* $u$ in the sense that $u \mid 1_R$, as the example $\mathcal Z$ shows.

I hope these remarks clarify the situation.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: Well, how do we get that $c,d$ are units? I don't see it, can you elaborate? Actually, am i confusing the terms "unit" and $1$ as an multiplicative identity?

Comment: @MichalDvořák:  It is easily possible to mix up $1_R$ and general units, especially when one is just starting out with the concepts.  I hope the remarks I added to my answer helped.  If not, feel free to get back to me.  Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, i see it now, i confused these two terms totally. I just have to make order in the naming. So, **unitary rings** are rings containing $1$ and **ring with unity** or **ring with units** (as i saw it too) are rings in which there are no divisors of 0 (that is, its Integral Domain) and there are units (e.g. invertible elements) that is.. some $u$ such that there is some $v$ s.t. $uv=vu=1$. Now, just logically, any ring with unity is a unitary ring, right? Because that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Well, I'd have to go back and re-read the textbooks or wikipedia or something, but my take on it is that  ***unital ring*** and ***ring with unity*** are the same, and mean $\exists 1_R \in R$; the term ***unitary ring*** is not used much in this context; a ***ring with units*** may or may not have divisors of zero.  Hope this helps.  Cheers!

Comment: Well, what confused me, was this link https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ideal_of_Unit_is_Whole_Ring. In the theorem, they speak about invertible elements, but if you click on "Ring with unity" one gets to page which says that ring with unity is a ring containing multiplication identity :/. But nvm, wikipedia might lie sometime, thanks for deeper explanations, i think I am ok now, cheers!

Comment: Certainly an ideal $I$ with $1_R \in I$ is the whole ring, since $r \in R$, $1_R \in I$ implies that $r = r1_R \in I$!  And the same is true for invertibles, if $u \in I$ and $uv = 1_R$ then $1_R \in I$ etc.

Comment: What I meant was that if $ab=1$ then there must be $1\in R$ because R is, by definition, closed under multiplication.

Comment: @MichalDvořák:  if $ab = 1_R$, then for sure $1_R \in R$!